# Safari Bug? When scrolling past, a fixed div element is half on top half under an image element?

Tags: html, css, position

I have a fixed div at the top of my webpage with a `background-color: black`. I also have an image in the middle of my webpage. (https://imgur.com/UteGyt6)

When I scroll passed the image, the div cuts the image in half. (https://imgur.com/y4wnKUT)

I am trying to make the div go under the image so when the div scrolls past the image is on top & visible.

Struggling to find the solution - any help would be great!

Looking to accomplish this - https://jsfiddle.net/q432wcx7/
(Code working in Chrome...not Safari)

**index.html**

```
<div class="logodiv"> </div>

<a href="./index.html"><img src="./assets/img/logoI.png" class="logo" alt="Logo"></a>
```

**style.css**

```
.logo {
  width: 500px;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1000;
  top: 240px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
}


.logodiv{
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  height: 184px;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  background-color: black;
  z-index: 1000;
}
```

Comment: can you post a link to a fiddle

Comment: It's working in fiddle (https://jsfiddle.net/q432wcx7/) as it is in Chrome. It's just Safari that's playing up :/

Answer (score 0):

This issue is very common - and is a bug in Safari.

Try this instead:

```
.logo {
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
  width: 500px;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1000;
  top: 240px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  }

.logodiv{
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  height: 185px;
  top: 0 !important;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  background-color: black;
  z-index: -1000;
}
```

I do not have safari so I can't text this fully but I think it is right. If it is not, just tell me and I will change my answer.

Comment: Thank you for your response! It didn't work unfortunately. I also have a jquery function that changes the position of the image element to fixed when I scroll down more.. Changing the position from absolute to fixed might also have an impact on this bug..

`$(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > 200) {
      $('.logo').css({ position: 'fixed', top: '0', }); 
    } else {
      $('.logo').css({ position: 'absolute', top: '200px' });
    }
});`

Comment: I am not sure then. Sorry

Comment: No worries - have a nice day!